# Excel Worksheet formulas to perform the autofill

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, autofill, worksheet

I'm looking for a formula that will allow me to type a name into one cell of an excell sheet, and have other cells auto-fill. I'd like to know the formula for this as well as how to apply it to the sheet.

Example:

Employee Name: Joseph Kelly
Email adress: jkelly@skender.com
Password: jkelly123

After entering these fields, I'd like the other fields to auto-fill with jkelly

example:

Username: jkelly
password: jkelly123
enter username at the prompt\ jkelly or jkelly123

Comment: Your example is a little confusing. Are you trying to get a person to enter Employee Name, Email Address and Password then have Excel return the User Name?

Comment: Modified answer to suit Formula specifically, since VBA tag is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use Excel Functions:**  check these out

[Split text using Left, Mid, Right, in excel formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Split-text-among-columns-by-using-functions-c2930414-9678-49d7-89bc-1bf66e219ea8) Numerous examples here.

**This will get you the email user name in a formula:**

For this example, the email is in B2

```
D2 =LEFT(B2, SEARCH("@",B2,1)-1)  
    'The -1 at the end removes the @ symbol.
E2 =RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-SEARCH("@",B2,1))
```

[image: FORMULA]

**Some useful links:**

[INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) : Returns references inside formulas.
[CONCATENTATE](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/CONCATENATE-function-870e82a1-d47d-440e-9a77-23e7639eda1d) : Allows you to blend string together

**Two examples of Concatenate:**
You can of course leave out the " ", that is simply to add a space between the two text values.

```
A1 = Harry
B1 = Smith
C1 = Concatenate(A1, " ", B1) 'Result = "Harry Smith"
or
C1 = A1 & " " & B1 'Result = "Harry Smith"
C1 = A1 & B1 'Result = "HarrySmith"
```

**In VBA,**  Just take this and modify it. You can build pretty much whatever you need **using Split.**  Originally the question was tagged with VBA, so I will leave this in the answer although since, the tag has been removed:

```
Sub Splitter()

Dim tempValue As String
Dim tempUser As String
Dim emailParts() As String

    tempValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    emailParts() = Split(tempValue, "@")

    tempUser = emailParts(0)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1) = tempUser
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1) = "You can blend " & tempUser & " with any text"

End Sub
```

[image: VBA Result]

Comment: How would I use the CONCATENATE? I've attempted it before but it doesnt work out.